# Store all ggplot2 plots from environment in a list

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, environment

I need to change all the labels (titles/subtitles) from a script that creates close to 100 hundred plots -- all different. Instead of changing the script code I'd like to loop through all plots and add a new `labs` function. This way nothing is altered from the original. To do this I need to get all ggplot2 objects into list.

My question is: How can one store all `ggplot2` objects in the environment into a list?

The code below should create eleven `ggplot2` plots and store them in the environment (want to do the reverse .. get them into a list from the environment).

```
library(tidyverse)

# Make a lot of ggplots using mtcars

all_plots <- list()

all_plots <- map(names(mtcars), 
    possibly(function(x){
  mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(mpg, x))+
    geom_point()
}, NULL)) %>% 
  set_names(names(mtcars))

# function to add all ggplots to the environemnt
list_environment <- function(x) {
  if(is.list(x)) { 
    list2env(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    lapply(x, test)
  }
}

list_environment(all_plots)

ls()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First collect the names of all your `ggplot` objects in the environment.  You can loop through `ls()` and check if each object has 'ggplot' in its class (this works for your example):

```
my_ggplot_names=ls()[which(sapply(ls(),function(x) class(get(x))[2]=="ggplot"))]
```

Then it's easy to use `mget` to collect all the objects with those names into a list:

```
my_listed_ggplots=mget(my_ggplot_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the plots in the list have no names.

```
library(ggplot2)
all_plots <- replicate(10, 
                       ggplot(mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 10),], aes(y=mpg, x=hp)) +
                         geom_point(),
                       simplify=F)
```

This list has no names,

```
names(all_plots)
# NULL
```

and `list2env` won't work.

```
list2env(all_plots, envir=.GlobalEnv)
# Error in list2env(all_plots, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
#   names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

Works when we name the list objects using `setNames`.

```
all_plots <- setNames(all_plots, sprintf("p%s", seq(all_plots)))
list2env(all_plots, envir=.GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "all_plots" "p1"        "p10"       "p2"        "p3"       
# [6] "p4"        "p5"        "p6"        "p7"        "p8"       
# [11] "p9"
```